# Best way to concatenate strings

Tags: c#, string, if-statement, concatenation

```
String outputFile = String.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\r\n", x.url, x.company, x.country, x.vendor,);

if (client.cf.is_cis == true)
{
    outputFile = String.Format("{0}\r\n", x.cis);
}

if (client.cf.is_firmographic == true)
{
    outputFile = String.Format("{0}\t{1}\r\n", x.revenue, x.employee);
}

writerCustomerTxt.Write(outputFile);
```

I have a set of strings that I am trying to output, but obviously with the code above, the output is being overrided if any of the if statements are true. I believe that string concatenation is the solution to this issue. What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Use [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx), read the [docs](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/4675/stringbuilder#t=201608042040323782465)

Comment: There is no concatenation in your code. you are replacing the output value

Comment: @DavidG: There is no reason to use StringBuilder for the given code sample.

Comment: @DavidG: Ah, you're probably right on that last bit.

Comment: use the `+=` operator...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to get exactly what you are asking, but using a `StringBuilder` to build up your string, this will work:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

builder.AppendFormat("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\r\n",
    x.url, x.company, x.country, x.vendor);

if (client.cf.is_cis == true)
{
    builder.AppendFormat("{0}\r\n",
        x.cis);
}

if (client.cf.is_firmographic == true)
{
    builder.AppendFormat("{0}\t{1}\r\n",
        x.revenue, x.employee);
}

writerCustomerTxt.Write(builder.ToString());
```

Comment: Odds are pretty high that this is going to perform worse than string concatenation, given that there is at most 2 concatenations, and often 0 or 1.

Comment: You're right, but I suspect this code isn't going to be called a thousand times per second and it's a nice intro to StringBuilder.

Comment: Using a tool in an inappropriate context *isn't* a good intro into the tool.  It would encourage the use of it in other similarly inappropriate contexts.  Using it in situations where it's actually the right tool for the job is the right way to introduce a tool, as it means you learn how to use it inappropriately.  You're going to out of your way to spend *more* time and effort to make a *less* efficient tool that's *not* representative of when it should be used.

Comment: With this particular example, I suspect StringBuilder will outperform pure string concatenation anyway.

Comment: If both `if` conditions are always true, it's likely to be very similar.  Any time any one of them isn't true then it's unquestionably worse.

Comment: Actually I think even with a single true condition, the format strings will make SB win out.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of concatenating a string is by using the `+=` operator:

```
String outputFile = String.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\r\n", x.url, x.company, x.country, x.vendor);

if (client.cf.is_cis == true)
{
    outputFile += String.Format("{0}\r\n", x.cis);
}

if (client.cf.is_firmographic == true)
{
    outputFile += String.Format("{0}\t{1}\r\n", x.revenue, x.employee);
}

writerCustomerTxt.Write(outputFile);
```

By the way, if you are not passing any argument over here, then you can remove the **`,`**:

```
String.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\r\n", x.url, x.company, x.country, x.vendor, );
                                                                             ^^^
```